# Running docker-compose up test inside github action to run tests

Tags: php, docker, github-actions

```
name: Run Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run-tests:
    name: Run Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    container:
      image: docker:latest
      options: --privileged

    services:
      docker:
        image: docker:19.03.12
        options: --privileged
        ports:
          - 2376:2376

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Run tests
      id: test
      run: |
        docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up test --abort-on-container-exit --exit-code-from app
        echo "::set-output name=exit_code::${?}"
        if [ ${{ steps.test.outputs.exit_code }} -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "Tests passed! Running another command here"
          # Replace the echo command with your desired command
        else
          echo "Tests failed"
          exit 1
        fi
  print-continuing:
    name: Print Continuing
    needs: run-tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ needs.run-tests.result == 'success' }}
    
    steps:
    - name: Print continuing
      run: echo "Continuing..."
```

I have this github action.

```
# Use the official PHP image
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
        unzip \
        git \
        && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install Laravel Installer
RUN composer global require laravel/installer

# Add composer binaries to $PATH
RUN echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin" >> ~/.bashrc

# Expose port 8000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 8000

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

I have this dockerfile.

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Laravel Application
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_DATABASE: laravel
      DB_USERNAME: laraveluser
      DB_PASSWORD: laravelpassword

  # MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: laraveluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravelpassword
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql # Mount SQL script into the container
        # Test Service
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
      - app
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_DATABASE: laravel # You may want to use a separate database for testing
      DB_USERNAME: laraveluser
      DB_PASSWORD: laravelpassword
    command: ["sh", "-c", "php vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml && php vendor/bin/codecept run"]
```

When I run docker-compose up test, I see that my tests run successfully, because the browser opens app:8000 to run the codeception tests, but when I test the github action by using: act -j run-tests

```
[+] Running 3/3
|  ✔ Container laravel-todo-db-1    Recreated4.6s
|  ✔ Container laravel-todo-app-1   Recreated10.8s
|  ✔ Container laravel-todo-test-1  Recreated0.3s
| Attaching to test-1
| test-1  | Could not open input file: vendor/bin/phpunit
| test-1 exited with code 1
| Aborting on container exit...
[+] Stopping 1/0
|  ✔ Container laravel-todo-test-1  Stopped0.0s
| ::set-output name=exit_code::0
| sh: 0: unknown operand
| Tests failed
```

So I am trying to make it work, but cannot figure out what's going wrong.